# H.264/MP2T over HTTP ExoPlayer

Tags: h.264, mpeg2-ts, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am using this code for playing a simple MPEG-TS using HLS on ExoPlayer:

```
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(new BufferPool(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE));
String userAgent = getUserAgent(mContext);
Log.d(TAG, userAgent);
HlsMasterPlaylist manifest = newSimpleMasterPlaylist("http://192.168.1.1/rtp/239.0.0.77:8208");
DataSource dataSource = new HttpDataSource(userAgent, null, null);
HlsChunkSource chunkSource = new HlsChunkSource(dataSource, manifest);
HlsSampleSource sampleSource = new HlsSampleSource(chunkSource, loadControl,
VIDEO_BUFFER_SEGMENTS * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE, true, 2);
MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource,
MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT, 100, mainHandler, null, 50);
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);
exoPlayer.prepare(videoRenderer,audioRenderer);
// Pass the surface to the video renderer.
exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

With this other method:

```
private HlsMasterPlaylist newSimpleMasterPlaylist(String mediaPlaylistUrl) {
return new HlsMasterPlaylist(Uri.parse(""),
Collections.singletonList(new Variant(mediaPlaylistUrl, 0)));
}
```

And it does not work. I get:

```
11-03 09:56:10.785: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 8% free 4422K/4780K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
11-03 09:56:14.005: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 7% free 5383K/5732K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
11-03 09:56:18.085: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 6% free 6663K/7024K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
11-03 09:56:25.075: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 4% free 8392K/8724K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
11-03 09:56:33.115: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 4% free 10697K/11036K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
11-03 09:56:44.155: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 3% free 13707K/14096K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
11-03 09:56:58.485: D/dalvikvm(10907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 3% free 17741K/18108K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
```

I think that with a single MPEG2TS file I can create a single media playlist with this code and It would work, but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently see MPEG-TS (or MP2T) support in ExoPlayer.

What makes you believe this approach would work?

Note: What is "HlsChunkSource"?  I don't find a reference to it in the standard ExoPlayer source code.

Comment: You probably need to check out the dev-hls branch of ExoPlayer.